Trying to understand /var/log/auth.log entries ('preauth') with iptables
I have some entries in /var/log/auth.log that still appear after trying to ban them:
Failed password for root from `<some.ip>` port 49102 ssh2
Connection closed by authenticating user randomuser `<some.ip>` port 49102 [preauth]

I am under the impression that 'INPUT' iptable chain is the entries that are supposed to ban connections from a specific IP.
I have entries in my iptables:
INPUT 60       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       <ip.range.0>/24      0.0.0.0/0
(I am banning the /24 subset of IPs, alot of them are reported on abuseipdb.com)
Questions

The auth.log shows the 'preauth' entries, I am not sure if these IPs are banned
Is INPUT the general chain to use for sshd connections?
What is the 'preauth' entry, is this when the connection is initiated, but before the iptables rule 'applies'?

I appreciate any clarifications, thanks!
More information
As requested by @paladin, my jail.local :
(By the way the topic implied that I already had iptables installed)
I had findtime on 30 minutes, but alot of IPs were doing ~5 attempts in ~2 hrs 30 minutes, effectively bypassing this rule.

jail.local:

[sshd]
enabled = true
bantime=2h
maxretry=4
findtime=3h
banaction=ufw

action_abuseipdb = abuseipdb
apikey_abuseipd = <api_key>

action = %(action_)s
         %(action_abuseipdb)s[abuseipdb_apikey="%%(apikey_abuseipd)", abuseipdb_category="18,22"]


Recidive jail:
recidive.conf:

[recidive]
enabled=true
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
bantime  = 2w
findtime = 12h
# Exceed this and 'recidive' jail will trigger.
maxretry = 4

My original questions still remains:
Consider this example
Please have a look at the iptables rules below, this range was banned before I asked these questions yesterday, the only new entry is the entry added by ufw (inside the ufw status as well as IP tables)
To reiterate, refer to my original questions.  Basically; why does it seem like auth.log has entries for this IP until or up to when ufw adds its entry into its own chain

Last entry in fail2ban.log
/var/log/fail2ban.log:

**2024-08-23 12:07:46,779** fail2ban.actions        [3666125]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 157.245.98.138


Analyzing auth.log for the IP

**sudo tail -n 200 auth.log | grep '157.245.98'**

Aug 23 11:56:23 my-server sshd[3666307]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.245.98.138  user=a_user
Aug 23 11:56:24 my-server sshd[3666307]: Failed password for a_user from 157.245.98.138 port 51026 ssh2
Aug 23 11:56:25 my-server sshd[3666307]: Received disconnect from 157.245.98.138 port 51026:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 23 11:56:25 my-server sshd[3666307]: Disconnected from authenticating user a_user 157.245.98.138 port 51026 [preauth]
Aug 23 12:00:16 my-server sshd[3667360]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.245.98.138  user=a_user
Aug 23 12:00:18 my-server sshd[3667360]: Failed password for a_user from 157.245.98.138 port 38102 ssh2
Aug 23 12:00:18 my-server sshd[3667360]: Received disconnect from 157.245.98.138 port 38102:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 23 12:00:18 my-server sshd[3667360]: Disconnected from authenticating user a_user 157.245.98.138 port 38102 [preauth]
Aug 23 12:04:03 my-server sshd[3668693]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.245.98.138  user=a_user
Aug 23 12:04:06 my-server sshd[3668693]: Failed password for a_user from 157.245.98.138 port 53412 ssh2
Aug 23 12:04:08 my-server sshd[3668693]: Received disconnect from 157.245.98.138 port 53412:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 23 12:04:08 my-server sshd[3668693]: Disconnected from authenticating user a_user 157.245.98.138 port 53412 [preauth]
Aug 23 12:07:44 my-server sshd[3669508]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.245.98.138  user=a_user
Aug 23 12:07:46 my-server sshd[3669508]: Failed password for a_user from 157.245.98.138 port 40494 ssh2
Aug 23 12:07:46 my-server sshd[3669508]: Received disconnect from 157.245.98.138 port 40494:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
**Aug 23 12:07:46 my-server sshd[3669508]: Disconnected from authenticating user a_user 157.245.98.138 port 40494 [preauth]**


Extracting all rules for matching IP in all chains
(Banning DOCKER-USER for https requests from same IP range)

sudo iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers | awk '/Chain/ {chain=$2} $0 ~ /157.245.98/ {print chain, $0}'

**INPUT 53       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       157.245.98.0/24      0.0.0.0/0**
DOCKER-USER 4        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       157.245.98.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
ufw-user-input 1        3   180 REJECT     all  --  *      *       *157.245.98.138       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable*


Confirming that ufw added a new REJECT state for this IP

**sudo ufw status**

Anywhere                   REJECT      157.245.98.138


If your goal is to ban unauthorized "users", take a look at the program "fail2ban".

I have fail2ban accompanied but it appears to not ban these IPs, I have created an sshd and recidive jail rule set.
I would still want to understand what these entries in my question are doing.

I probably have to rephrase fail2ban not banning them; I see the IPs I am trying to ban inside the /var/log/fail2ban.log, but the ruleset for neither 'catches' them. May I post my ruleset for assistance in this regard? (Still need the rest answered)

For fail2ban being able to ban IPs you also need to have installed iptables.

PS please post your jail.local config file of fail2ban

@paladin I added more information, it took a while, sorry for the delay.
